# NoReverseMatch Unless Url Is In Main Project Urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a project called 'my_project' and within that project I have an app called 'my_app' so I have two urls.py files. All of my url's for my_app are located within it's urls.py file and work correctly, except one. That one is 'download_file'. My site works when this is included in my_project's urls.py, but when it's in my_app's urls.py I get a `NoReverseMatch` error on page load.

I don't know why this url only works when it's located in my main projects url's folder. I suspect it has something to do with the regex, though I can't figure it out.

The user would be on this page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_area/username/classes
```

then click the 'download' link:

```
<a href="{% url 'download_file' file_path=item.instance.user_file %}" target='_blank'>{{ item.instance.filename }}</a>
```

my_project.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# reference to my_app
re_path(r'^user_area/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/', include('my_app.urls')),
]

# this works
url(r'^download_file/(?P<file_path>(.+)\/([^/]+))$', users_views.DownloadFile.as_view(), name='download_file'),
]
```

my_app.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('classes', views.classes, name='classes'),

# if I remove the url from my_project.py this one returns NoReverseMatch on page load
url(r'^download_file/(?P<file_path>(.+)\/([^/]+))$', users_views.DownloadFile.as_view(), name='download_file'),
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how `my_app.urls` is referenced in your project urls.py?

Comment: Sure. I added it

Comment: OK. Can you also show your template code for this 'delete' link?

Comment: No worries, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because your [URL template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) is providing only one parameter: `file_path`.

This works when the URL is declared in your project urls.py, because only one parameter is needed.

When you try to use the URL in `my_app.urls`, you need to also provide the `username` parameter. You will need to use something like:

```html
<a href="{% url 'download_file' username=request.user.username file_path=item.instance.user_file %}" target='_blank'>{{ item.instance.filename }}</a>
```